# Python gRpc GetTopChannels returns empty channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

I used the `channelz` to debug my gRpc service, but I always find that the `GetTopChannels` returns empty.

#### Environment

- Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python gRpc 1.27.2
- Python 3.7.3

I have tried the offical demo in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/debug/debug_server.py, and use `evans` to make a gRpc call. In the response, only `{“end”: true}` returns. But other methods are work, e.g. `GetServerSockets`.

Comment: I upgrade gRpc to 1.29.0, but it does not work too. Is there any problem with my usage?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstand the concept. The channel in `channelz` refers to "client".